# How to manage DAOs using single connection

Tags: java, dao

I have read about DAO from here and I find it really interesting but a few things are still missing me.
I would like to use the Interface to implement for two different data sources - one is a Socket connection, the other a Database connection.

For this I do the following:

```
public class databasePartDAOImplementation extends Database implements PartDAO {
    //implementation
}
```

and the Database class has a constructor and some methods for managing this connection. How can I set up these classes, so I could instantiate one Database connection and then uses multiple DAOs all using this one connection?

I'm thinking of creating and instance of Database() and casting it into all the DAOs when needed, but I am not sure of any downfalls to this.

The Database class I use looks like this

```
public class Database
{
    protected Connection connection;
    public Database() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = null;
        try
        {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.s3db");
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }
}
```

tl;dr Would using this be a good idea of accessing the db?

```
Database db = new Database();
databasePartDAOImplementation dao = (databasePartDAOImplementation) db;
dao.getAllRecords();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are partially correct regarding the point that the DAO should manage the connection with its data source to obtain and store data.  But, as you have asked, how can we have all DAOs share the same connection?  Let me shed some light by considering of the following strategies and then things will fall into place:

- **Automatically generating DAO code:** Normally, there exists a relationship between your business objects, their DAOs and their underlying DB tables.  Automatic code generation can take place using that relationship.  In complex cases, you may use third party tools for code generation.  May not be what you are looking for, but I just wanted to put it out there.
- **DAO Factory:**

  - In a scenario where you are not dealing with different data sources (apparently this is not your scenario), you would create a single DAO factory class and use the *Factory Method* pattern to create the different DAOs used by your application.  The DAO factory would be the class to manage the connection to the data source in this case.
  - In the scenario where you are dealing with different data sources (this is most likely your scenario), you would create an abstract DAO factory (this is the *Abstract Factory* pattern).  Then, again, using the *Factory Method* pattern, your abstract DAO factory creates the concrete DAO factories for each of your specific data sources.  Each concrete DAO factory would be responsible of two main tasks:

    1. Creating a DAO for each kind of data access
    2. Implementing a static method (e.g. `createConnection`) that takes care of creating a connection with its specific data source.  You should consider connection pooling implementation and usage for that matter.

    All the DAOs that are created by a concrete DAO factory would then be able to call that static method (`createConnection`) to obtain a connection to the specific data source.  This connection would essentially be the same connection across all DAOs of the concrete DAO factory.

*Ideas presented in this answer are based on the detailed article [Core J2EE Patterns - Data Access Object](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html).*